# Не вижу пакеты udp в режиме multicast на другом хосте

Tags: сеть, udp

На физическом хоте (OS Windows) установлен VirtualBox c OS Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). В Ubuntu установлен Docker, в котором и запускаю Java приложение.
Оно отправляет по сети на другой компьютер пакеты по протоколу udp в режиме multicast по адресу 224.1.1.244 и порту 53000. Контейнер с этим приложением запускаю через docker-compose.

Запускаю wireShark и вижу свои пакеты на сетевом адаптере ETh физического хоста.
Но на другом физическом хосте я их ни могу обнаружить ни с помощью того же wireShark ни на одном из сетевых интерфейсов.

Причем если запускаю это же приложение, но на физическом хосте. То все работает, на другом хосте видно мои пакеты.
В чем может быть проблема?
Куда смотреть?

Адрес хоста: 5.15.1.114

Адрес виртуалки: 5.15.1.6

маска у всех 255.255.255.0

Comment: В качестве источника другой ip, больше разницы не заметил

Comment: Скорее всего, виртуалка находится в другой подсети. Покажите IP маску подсети всех трёх участников

Comment: м, надеюсь, что они "в одной подсети" по факту (айпи-маски совпадают, это уже хорошо). Такие бродкасты за пределы сети так просто не выходят. А тип сети бридж?

Comment: у виртуалки бридж выбран. Да, я уже понял, что с ними есть такая проблема. Щас пытаюсь разобраться, может что-то в настройках нашей сети мешает.